# Hasura endpoint as environment variable

Tags: yaml, dotenv, hasura

I'm trying to check in my Hasura `config.yaml` file in a way that would be agnostic to my Hasura endpoint. The idea is that each developer will check out the project and work on a different Hasura instance, and then we would want to deploy and apply migrations separately to staging and production servers.

Is there, for instance, a way to make config.yaml get values from an `.env` file?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `config.yaml.template` file that contains the endpoints.

In this file you can define the endpoint like this:

```
endpoint: ${HASURA_ENDPOINT}
```

On startup of your hasura container you can generate a `config.yaml` file with `envsubst`:

```
envsubst '$HASURA_ENDPOINT' < /my_hasura_dir/config.yaml.template > /my_hasura_dir/config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the —endpoint flag when executing commands. Similarly you can use flags for passing in admin secret and so on. Alternatively you can also use environment variables.

Read more here https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/graphql-engine-flags/config-examples.html

Comment: Thank you. I looked at https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/deployment/graphql-engine-flags/reference.html but found no mention of an environment variable for endpoint.

Comment: I also tried `HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT` and `HASURA_GRAPHQL_END_POINT` with no success.